# WooCommerce REST API attribute filter on Product list not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am using the latest API v2. While the other filters like `min_price`, `category` etc. are working, the `attribute` and `attribute_terms` query params are not filtering the result set.

I have an attribute `Color` and I am invoking the API from a node.js client as :

```
var WooCommerceAPI = require('woocommerce-api');
var WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
  url: 'http://localhost/index.php',
  consumerKey: '***',
  consumerSecret: '***',
  wpAPI: true,
  version: 'wc/v2'
});

WooCommerce.getAsync('products?attribute=pa_color').then(function(result){

        var data = JSON.parse(result.toJSON().body);
        console.log(data);
    });
```

How can I actually filter by attribute ? Tried other combinations e,g.  `attribute=Color` , `attribute=color`. Still the result isn't filtered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the most recent WooCommerce REST API documentation: http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-products

WooCommerce seems to have a terrible history of REST APIs. They had API V1, V2 and V3 and then changed to WP REST API and created a V1 and V2. Of course searching on Google for a correct way to do it sucks badly.

This should be the correct way to do it:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products/?attribute=pa_color&attribute_term=15
```

or

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products/?attribute=pa_color&attribute_term=green
```

**Note:** *It is important to use attribute TOGETHER with attribute_term.*

I guess the former way to do it was like this:

```
products?filter[meta_key]=pa_color&filter[meta_value]=green
```

or like this:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products?attribute[pa_color]=green
```

but it seems like ***this does not work anymore in the WooCommerce WordPress API V2***.

Comment: yes using  attribute together with attribute_term actually solved the issue. But they didn't mention it in their API doc.

Comment: Yes seems like they definitly should make a better documentation with examples etc.

Comment: is it possible to use multiple attributes with values in the query string ?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. The correct way to do it:

```
products?attribute=pa_color&attribute_term=50
```

You must replace the name of attribute terms with ID of attribute terms. Is working for me.

P.S. I'm using latest version of wc/v2.

Comment: Hey, I tried this in V3 and its not working. Do you have any idea how it works in V3?

Comment: For V3 it works as well. Make sure that for the attribute_term you are using the ID of the term, not the slug.
You can find it in the documentation as well: "attribute_term - Limit result set to products with a specific attribute term ID (required an assigned attribute)."